# How to integrate CPCL to Android Java?

Tags: android, bluetooth, barcode-printing

Can you help me please. I tried this link:
(https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/comtec/PROMAN-CPCL_RevY.pdf)
But its difficult to understand.

Comment: What device are you using? have you tried the Zebra SDK?

The easiest way to test this is to send a string like the examples shown in the pdf you link to the printer via TCP/IP, make sure the printer you're using supports CPCL.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Im currently using Zebra EZ320.